# XCode Source Control History not showing files

Tags: xcode, git

XCode 7.1 (7B91b)
*Source Control > History > Show modified files*
Git diffs for some files won't show, stuck at Loading... (like for StaticData.mm), while other do will show (eg. Info.plist)
[image: Stuck at Loading...]

**Edit:**
Such standalone Git GUI tools like XGit or SourceTree show repo and diffs properly, it means the repo itself seems to be ok, as suggested by Tim Biegeleisen, it may be an "XCode Git plugin bug", anyway currently I use external git tool...

Comment: May I ask what exact diff are you trying to view in XCode?

Comment: Differences made to source files. I make a change, commit and after that click on commited file in the list

Comment: No, I'm trying to see if, for example, the reason there is no diff is because XCode cannot find an earlier commit on that branch.  Did you do such a sanity check?

Comment: Just now I tried to make change to StaticData.mm, commited it and still get Loading... How do I check for sanity?

Comment: OK then it looks like there is a real problem, since we now know you have a history.  What does `git status` show you from the Git bash?

Comment: It gives me
`On branch master2
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: My feeling is that this is a glitch in the XCode Git plugin.  As I'm not a iOS developer, I'm not the best person to answer this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93958/discussion-between-schmidt9-and-tim-biegeleisen).